# Unnecessary Material Coming up at the end of Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

i Just made a website with the help of Word Press Tutorials over the net (theme i used is syndey), i am learning all of this but having some issues, i have already checked pages twice and the info i added but cannot find what's wrong, someone help me with:
Extra Unnecessary material showing up at the end of the pages, i haven't added any such material on my own but still its showing at the end of all pages (home, about, contact).
Thanks in Advance.

http://www.kartikahuja.com/

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that the extra unnecessary material is the footer.
In order to change your footer to the desired content follow this tutorial:
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-wordpress-appearance/change-footer-text-brand